# How to find the max value from a table with group by

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have below table(player) columns

```
playerId  score  teamId
```

this table has all players information for all teams. PlayerID is the primary column. Each team includes multiple players so there are many duplicate values on teamId. Score is the points for each player.

I want to write a hive-sql to query the max score player for each team. Below is the query I tried:

```
select max(score) score, teamId from player group by teamId
```

this query works fine but it only shows teamId and the max score. I want to query the playerId as well. I got below errors if I add playerId on the select column:

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:32 Invalid column reference 'playerId'
```

it seems that I can only get the column from group by. How can I write the query to find the playerId?

Comment: What do you want to see in case the highest score is shared by multiple players? An arbitrary player? Multiple rows? A single row holding an array of players?

Comment: @Zhao Yi: Can you include the schema and sample data for better clarity in the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work unless two players have the same score on a team. In that case, it will return two rows for that team.

```
select a.score, a.teamId, b.playerId
from (
select max(score) as score, teamId 
from player 
group by teamId
) a
inner join player b
on a.teamId = b.teamId and a.score = b.score
```

Comment: I may not think this is the best answer, but it definitely does not deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

In Hive, you should do this using window functions:

```
select p.score, p.teamId
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by teamId order by score desc) as seqnum
      from player p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Doing a separate aggregation and join is the "old" ways of expressing such logic.  SQL has become more powerful in the past couple of decades.